# turn a select into a <ul>

Tags: javascript

Turn a select like this:

```
<select name="subject" onChange="mailsubject(this.value)">
    <option value="0">General Enquiry</option>
    <option value="1">Chatmaster Complaint</option>
    <option value="2">Chatmaster Application</option>
    <option value="3">Technical Issue</option>
</select>
```

Into a ul like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>General Enquiry</li>
    <li>Chatmaster Complaint</a></li>
    <li>Chatmaster Application</a></li>
    <li>Technical Issue</a></li>
</ul>
```

while still being able to use the js that has values that place certain forms into the field which ever form is picked on the select, but I would rather have a ul for it?

Comment: where do i send the invoice?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = $('<ul>');
$('#subject option').each(function() {
  $('<li>').text($(this).text()).appendTo(list);
});
list.appendTo($('body'));
$('#subject').remove();
```

check on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eT6k7/

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var html=''
    $('#subject option').each(function() {
     html= '<li>'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
    });

    $('#subject').replaceWith($('<ul>' + html + '</ul>'));
    });
```